# Not loading the go live page in the browser for vscode

Tags: vscode-extensions

When I press the go live option in vscode, Google Chrome opens but the page does not load and shows an error (This site can't be reached). What is the solution?

[image]

I deleted and reinstalled the go live plugin in vscode several times. vscode is also updated. The user settings are as follows:

```
{
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.useLocalIp": true,
    "liveServer.settings.port": 0,
}
```